# Show $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(2,X) \simeq \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-isomorphism

I am a beginner in abstract algebra and I am trying to prove $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(2,X) \simeq \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Let $\varphi : \mathbb{Z}[X] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. $\varphi$ is a homomorphism ring. We get the isomorphism if :

1. $\ker \varphi = (2,X)$ and
2. $\mathrm{Im} \varphi = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

But I had a few problems. I don't know if what I did is correct.

Proof of 1.

Let $P(X) : = \sum_{i = 0}^{+ \infty} a_iX^i \in \ker \varphi$ with $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}$. So $\varphi(P(X)) = \overline{0}$ because $\overline{0}$ is the zero-element of $\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$.

Since $\varphi$ is a homomorphism ring, then we get $\varphi(a_i X^i) = \overline{a_i X^i} = \overline{0}$. Here we get $\overline{a_i} = \overline{0}$ or $\overline{X^i} = \overline{0}$ i.e $ \ker \phi$ is generated by $0$ and $X$.

I get $0$ instead of $2$, I don't know why.

Proof of 2.

Let $\overline{k} \in \mathrm{Im} \varphi$, with $k = 0,1$, then $\exists P(X) \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ s.t $\varphi(P(X)) = \overline{k}$

And I don't know how to pursue. Thank you.

Comment: In $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, $\overline 0=\overline 2$

Comment: Presumably you defining $\varphi$ by taking the coefficient of $x^0$ and reducing mod 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

The ideal

$$I=(2,x)=\{2n +xq(x) \mid n \in \mathbb Z, \, q \in \mathbb Z[x]\}$$

is the kernel of the ring homeomorphism that maps $p \in \mathbb Z[x]$ to $\overline{p_0} \in \mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z$ where $p_0$ is the coefficient of degree $0$ of $p$.

Comment: In $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, we know $I = (2,X) = (2) + (X)$ and :

1) $(X) = \left\{ Xq(X) \mid q \in \mathbb{Z}[X] \right\} $ (ok)

2) $(2) = \left\{ 2q(X) \mid q \in \mathbb{Z}[X] \right\} $ and I don't know how to get
$$ (2) = \left\{ 2n \mid n \in \mathbb{Z} \right\} $$
Then $(X) + (2)$ is the sum of their element. Maybe I did a mistake somewhere

Comment: @Tohiea I’m not saying that $(2)=\{2n \mid n \in \mathbb Z\}$. Just prove the equality I wrote by double inclusion.